# Finding Newton method order of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I'm trying to determine how you find the order of convergence of newton's method. I have the formula $$\frac {|x^*-x_{n+1}|}{ |x^*-x_n|^q} = \alpha$$ I'm setting $q=2$ to test for quadratic convergence and as far as I know, if $\alpha > 0$ then the convergence is quadratic.

Approximate results for root from Newtons method with initial guess $-2$:

$$-2.45819577, 
-2.32858671, 
-2.31342784, 
-2.31322658$$

If I apply the formula, for each iteration, I get $\alpha$ values as:
$0.7308756055$,
$0.8530366402$,
$0$

Which does not make sense $\alpha$ should be $> 0$ since Newton convergences quadratically when the initial guess is close to the root?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, α (asymptotic error constant) does change along the iterations, but theorically, in order to be able to calculate the order, you should assume that once its reaching the convergence, it does **not** change and remains constant. So, in that scenario:
$$
\frac {|x^*-x_{n+1}|}{ |x^*-x_n|^q} = \alpha \\
\frac {|x^*-x_{n}|}{ |x^*-x_{n-1}|^q} = \alpha 
$$

Given that, you can expand with math :

$$
|x^*-x_{n+1}|\cdot|x^*-x_{n-1}|^q = |x^*-x_{n}|\cdot |x^*-x_n|^q \\
ln(|x^*-x_{n+1}|) +q \cdot ln(|x^*-x_{n-1}|) = ln(|x^*-x_{n}|) + q \cdot ln(|x^*-x_n|) \\
ln(|x^*-x_{n+1}|) - ln(|x^*-x_{n}|)= q \cdot ln(|x^*-x_n|) - q \cdot ln(|x^*-x_{n-1}|)  \\
ln(\frac{|x^*-x_{n+1}|}{|x^*-x_{n}|}) = q \cdot ln(\frac{|x^*-x_n|}{|x^*-x_{n-1}|}) \\
\therefore q \simeq \frac{ln(\frac{|x^*-x_{n+1}|}{|x^*-x_{n}|})}{ln(\frac{|x^*-x_n|}{|x^*-x_{n-1}|})}
$$

Now, with yours results given, with a simple code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ -2.45819577, -2.32858671, -2.31342784,-2.31322658 ])

np.log( np.absolute(a[3]-a[2]) / np.absolute(a[2] - a[1]) ) / np.log(  np.absolute(a[2] - a[1]) /  np.absolute(a[1] - a[0]) )
```

we can calculate the convergence order which gives us $$ q \simeq 2.013 $$ which confirms the convergence order of Newton-Raphson method.